# What is Bach doing in these pieces?

Tags: composition, j-s-bach

Is this a certain progression in both pieces?
Both parts are here slowed down: https://sndup.net/7w6t

The first part is from that piece

(2:18)

The second piece:

(18:51)
Is Bach doing here something which can be classified in terms of music theory? It sound very similar to my ears.

EDIT: something very similar happens here too

(20:48) What is this? Does it have a name?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are hearing the *sequence* musical device where a short segment of music is repeated but transposed up or down usually by step. Sometimes the transposition is diatonic other times it is chromatic.

You can refer to either *harmonic sequence* or *melodic sequence*. Often a sequence is both harmonic and melodic which is what these Bach examples sound like.